# OpenCV configure VS 2015

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I've searched extensively and checked everywhere I could find. I've got Visual Studio 2015 and OpenCV 3.0.0 . I haven't used OpenCV before and despite checking for tutorials on the matter. I cannot find any for 3.0.0 I've been attempting to run the test application:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
{
    cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
    return -1;
}

Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

if(! image.data ) // Check for invalid input
{
    cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); .
imshow( "Display window", image ); // Show our image inside it.

waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
return 0;
}
```

After a while I managed to get a lack of complaints about missing libraries (You include staticlib for instance:

```
D:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib
```

into the linker's additional library directories. 
However. I still cannot build the code (taken from http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to the OpenCV docs)
due to errors such as:

```
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'image' 31
```

This error only comes up when attempting to build. Intellisense has no complaints and accepts Mat as a class. 
I can also provide my Additional Dependencies and all other changed settings if it would be helpful.

Comment: You need to rebuild opencv with visual studio 2015 compiler. You're using the version prebuilt with vs2013.

Comment: Would I do that with CMake?

Comment: Yep.. A lot of tutorials online.

Comment: Thanks. I'll recompile the libraries for Visual Studio 2015. I knew I was missing something.